# How can i call a variable from one script.gs to another script.gs in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In here I am trying to pass/get a variable from Code.gs to NewFile.gs. I would like to pass a `folderId`which i get it from *input box* and use it in different file gs instead of inserting manually.

Here is the code:

**Code.gs**

```
 if (userInput == "yes") {

var folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);  
}

var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);                            
var parentName = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getName();
```

**NewFile.gs**

```
function newFileUpdate() {

var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId from input box");                            
var parentName = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId from input box").getName();
                
 getChildFiles(parentName, parent);
 getRootFiles(parentName, parent);
  }
```

So i would like to know a simple way for me to get the folder id from code.gs into NewFile.gs

Answer (score 2):

You can always pass variables around via function arguments.

Your **code.gs** can pass the variable you want to `newFileUpdate/0` by giving it a function arity of 1, which is to say *"Give the function an argument"* like...

**Code.gs**

```
// add variable
var folderId;

if (userInput == "yes") {    
    folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);  
}

var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);                            
var parentName = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getName();

// Send folderId to newFileUpdate/1
newFileUpdate(folderId);
```

**NewFile.gs**

```
// added argument folderId to function
function newFileUpdate(folderId) {
   var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);                            
   var parentName = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getName();
                
   getChildFiles(parentName, parent);
   getRootFiles(parentName, parent);
}
```

edit: Just realized I misunderstood the question and how you structured your code. You're trying to get the folderId down into your NewFile.gs